# Find the number of integer partitions with distinct parts of n

Tags: python, performance, integer, numbers, partition

> An integer partition with distinct parts of `n` is a decreasing list of positive integers which sum to `n`, in which no number occurs more than once.
>
> For example, there are 3 integer partitions of 5:
> `[5], [4,1], [3,2]`.
>
> Write a function which returns the number of integer partitions with distinct parts of `n`  where `1 <= n <= 600`.

Source: https://www.codewars.com/kata/6267a007e67fba0058725ad2

I wrote this code:

```py
import itertools
list_poss = [list(i) for j in range(1, n+1) for i in itertools.combinations(range(n+1), j) if sum(list(i)) == n and 0 not in list(i)]
```

but it is too slow and gives the following error : `Execution Timed Out (12000 ms)`.

How can I optimise this code further?

Comment: Please properly format your code.

Comment: Please explain the problem **clearly**

Comment: So for example input=100 and output=444793?

Comment: My code run to long with n>20 so i don't find with n = 100. I have for n = 20 output = 64

Comment: Please edit the question to say what the input is, what the output is, your example with 20, the link to the problem, and don't *command* us to do something (the "Write ...").

Comment: A link to this problem: https://www.codewars.com/kata/6267a007e67fba0058725ad2/train/python

Comment: I have an integer n in input, and I have to find all the number that sum up to n.
 I put all the possibilities in several lists, and I have to find the number of possibilities.
 each list must have different elements.
the output is the number of list who verify this conditions

 exemple n = 5
all the possibles lists are:
[5], [4, 1], [3, 2], [3, 1, 1], [2, 2, 1], [2, 1, 1, 1]
 but the lists [3, 1, 1], [2, 2, 1], [2, 1, 1, 1] have identical elements.
 so we delete them to obtain a list 2d:
 [[5], [4, 1], [3, 2]]
and the result is 3, because there are 3 lists in the 2d list.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a job for recursion.

Partitions for `n` will always have [n] on its own. Then for every number k from n-1 down to half of n (exclusively), partitions can be formed with k and the remainder of n (i.e. n-k):

```
from functools import lru_cache

@lru_cache(None)        # remember/reuse past results
def countParts(n):
    return 1 + sum(countParts(n-k) for k in range(n-1,n//2,-1))
```

output:

```
for n in range(1,20):
    print(n,countParts(n))

1 1
2 1
3 2
4 2
5 3
6 3
7 5
8 5
9 7
10 7
11 10
12 10
13 13
14 13
15 18
16 18
17 23
18 23
19 30

countParts(100) # 4914

countParts(600) # 38847071
```

To see what the partitions are, you can write a recursive generator using the same logic:

```
def genParts(n):
    yield [n]
    for k in range(n-1,n//2,-1):
        for p in genParts(n-k):
            yield [k,*p]

for n in range(1,10):
    print(n,*genParts(n))

1 [1]
2 [2]
3 [3] [2, 1]
4 [4] [3, 1]
5 [5] [4, 1] [3, 2]
6 [6] [5, 1] [4, 2]
7 [7] [6, 1] [5, 2] [4, 3] [4, 2, 1]
8 [8] [7, 1] [6, 2] [5, 3] [5, 2, 1]
9 [9] [8, 1] [7, 2] [6, 3] [6, 2, 1] [5, 4] [5, 3, 1]
```